# Query Object Access by Profile

Tags: apex, soql, profile, permissions, permission-sets

I have looked at the documentation and it seems the best I can do is query `ObjectPermissions` for `PermissionSet` access.

Is it possible to do the same for `Profile` instead of `PermissionSet`?

THANKS FOR THE ANSWERS! I wrote an Apex script based off sfdcfox's links to documentation. Hope this helps anyone who stumbles on this question.

```
Map<Id, Id> permSetProfileMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
List<ObjectPermissions> profileObjectPermList = new List<ObjectPermissions>();


For(PermissionSet ps : [SELECT Id, ProfileId 
        FROM PermissionSet 
        WHERE IsOwnedbyProfile = TRUE]) {


permSetProfileMap.put(ps.id, ps.ProfileId);
}



For(ObjectPermissions op : [SELECT id, ParentId, PermissionsCreate, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsDelete, PermissionsViewAllRecords, PermissionsModifyAllRecords, SobjectType 
            FROM ObjectPermissions 
            WHERE ParentId
            IN: permSetProfileMap.keySet()]) {

profileObjectPermList.add(op);

}



For (ObjectPermissions op: profileObjectPermList) {
System.debug('Profile Id: ' + permSetProfileMap.get(op.parentId) + ' , sObject: ' + op.sObjectType + ' , Create: ' + op.PermissionsCreate + ' , Read: ' + op.PermissionsRead + ' , Edit: ' + op.PermissionsEdit + ' , Delete: ' + op.PermissionsDelete + ' , View All Records: ' + op.PermissionsViewAllRecords + ' , Modify All Records: ' + op.PermissionsModifyAllRecords);

}
```

Comment: [Marginally helpful](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html).

Comment: @AdrianLarson Sorry if I rubbed you the wrong way. I figured the question was detailed enough to be posted.

Comment: You didn't rub me the wrong way. The link lays out what sfdcfox explained in more detail. I'm just not super familiar with it myself, so I didn't leave it as an answer. Did you not notice it's a link?

Comment: AHHH! I didnt realize it was a  link! I figured I was getting flak for the one liner question. Thank you brofessor for the link!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Profiles are replicated into a special type of [PermissionSet](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm). `IsOwnedByProfile` will be true, `ProfileId` will be set to the [Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_profile.htm)'s Id field. So, you can query PermissionSet to determine a profile's object, field, apex class, and Visualforce permissions via the associated security objects (e.g. ObjectPermissions). Also, see the [User Access Visualization](https://github.com/forcedotcom/user-access-visualization) open source code from salesforce to see how they render a user's profile and permission set permissions.