# Query Which Profiles Have Read Access To Specific Object?

Tags: soql, query, permissions

Since I couldn't think of how to write this query off the top of my head, I thought it might be worth sharing. **How can I query which `Profiles` have `Read` permission on a specific object?** I knew it would have something to do with `ObjectPermissions` and `PermissionSet`, but had to look up the documentation for both to piece it together.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first query I got to work was on the `ObjectPermissions` object:

```
SELECT Parent.Profile.Name FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = true AND SObjectType = 'MyObject__c'
```

This query gets exactly the data I wish, but in the Query Editor, gives the dreaded:

> [object Object]

[`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join) to the rescue! More palatable:

```
SELECT Profile.Name FROM PermissionSet
WHERE IsOwnedByProfile = true AND Id IN (
    SELECT ParentId FROM ObjectPermissions
    WHERE PermissionsRead = true
    AND SObjectType = 'MyObject__c'
)
```

Comment: note: https://github.com/forcedotcom/user-access-visualization which also caters for permission sets (as those can extend a running user's object access) -- taken from [sfdcfox answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/122579/2602)