# How can we get the list of user those who have the read permission on the case sObject?

Tags: soql, query, case, standard-objects

How can we get the list of user those who have the read permission on the `Case` sObject?

Comment: Do you mean populate a List<> in apex / via visualforce, or simply "see" a list of all those users (via workbench, query editor, anon apex etc.etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward to adapt my query from [my recent question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153986/query-which-profiles-have-read-access-to-specific-object) to your needs. I would just drop `IsOwnedByProfile` since any `PermissionSet` which gives access to the object would meet your criteria. If you just want the Ids you can get them in one query. If you want more information about the `User` records, you can obviously filter on those ids in a subsequent query.

```
Set<Id> userIdsWithAccess = new Map<Set<Id>();
for (PermisionSetAssignment assignment : [
    SELECT AssigneeId FROM PermissionSetAssignment
    WHERE PermissionSetId IN (
        SELECT ParentId FROM ObjectPermissions
        WHERE PermissionsRead = true
        AND SObjectType = 'Case'
    )
]) userIdsWithAccess.add(assignment.AssigneeId);

List<User> usersWithCaseAccess = [
    SELECT Username FROM User
    WHERE Id IN :userIdsWithAccess
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
List<ObjectPermissions> objPs = [ SELECT Id, ParentId, Parent.ProfileId, 
PermissionsRead, Parent.isOwnedByProfile  FROM ObjectPermissions where SobjectType = 'Case' and PermissionsRead = true ];
List<Id> profilesIds = new List<Id>();
List<Id> psIds = new List<Id>();
for (ObjectPermissions op: objPs) {
    if ( op.Parent.ProfileId != null ) {
        profilesIds.add( op.Parent.ProfileId );
    } else
        psIds.add( op.ParentId );
}
List<User> users = [select id, name from User where ProfileId IN: profilesIds ];
users.addAll( [select id, name from User where Id IN ( select AssigneeId from PermissionSetAssignment where PermissionSetId IN: psIds )] );
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ v: ' + users );
```

Variable users will contain list of users which have read permission to Case object.