# SFDC Organization-wide default + sharing rules

Tags: visualforce, soql, owd

I'm trying to query the OWD/Sharing rules for Account/Opportunity objects using SOQL to get data into a `Visualforce Page`.

Already took a look into the AccountSharing object, but it returns empty despite that under the `Setup` -> `Security Controls` -> `Sharing Settings` -> `Accounts` there are some Account Sharing Rules created.

I need to get it for an already calculated set of Users/profiles/Roles.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, is not about config by point and click, is to query the data using SOQL, something like SELECT If FROM ObjectSharingRule WHERE Role/User = 'Role/UserRecordId' and work with that dataset in APEX code.

Comment: That's not at all what I'm asking. I want to know why you want the OWD setting (which is not specific to any `User`/`Profile`/`Role`).

Comment: Thank you for your help. The reason is business is asking for a query, to identify/filter users and get what/where they have access based on profile/Roles/permission Sets/Sharing rules. I have now the Permission Sets, but cannot find anything about Sharing/OWD from SOQL p.o.v.

Comment: Okay, `Role` has basically nothing to do with that (it can control record level access but not object level). Are you *just* trying to look at `Account`?

Comment: Account and Opportunity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the **[`ObjectPermissions`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_objectpermissions.htm)** object. It's a bit convoluted, so it ends up significantly easier to ask "Which `Users`/`Profiles` have `Read` permission?" than it is to ask "What are all the permissions each `User`/`Profile` has?" It will increase your governor consumption, but keep the complexity of your code from growing too crazy. I'm not sure if you even care about any permissions besides `Read`, so I will just address that permission here.

I answered some very similar questions that provide building blocks here, so I will reference them below.

---

First take a look at [Query Which Profiles Have Read Access To Specific Object?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153986/query-which-profiles-have-read-access-to-specific-object) which can give you the `Profile` level view:

```
SELECT Profile.Name FROM PermissionSet
WHERE IsOwnedByProfile = true AND Id IN (
    SELECT ParentId FROM ObjectPermissions
    WHERE PermissionsRead = true
    AND SObjectType = 'Account'
)
```

You can iterate that `List<PermissionSet>` to get just the names if that meets your needs, or you can change `Profile.Name` to `ProfileId` and collect those Ids to query a `List<Profile>` if you need more data.

---

Next, take a look at [How can we get the list of user those who have the read permission on the case sObject?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/154687/how-can-we-get-the-list-of-user-those-who-have-the-read-permission-on-the-case-s?noredirect=1&lq=1) which is subtly different but shows you how to get `User` level access:

```
Set<Id> userIdsWithAccess = new Map<Set<Id>();
for (PermisionSetAssignment assignment : [
    SELECT AssigneeId FROM PermissionSetAssignment
    WHERE PermissionSetId IN (
        SELECT ParentId FROM ObjectPermissions
        WHERE PermissionsRead = true
        AND SObjectType = 'Account'
    )
]) userIdsWithAccess.add(assignment.AssigneeId);

List<User> usersWithCaseAccess = [
    SELECT Username FROM User
    WHERE Id IN :userIdsWithAccess
];
```

---

That should get you started. If you want to add in `Edit` permission, you'll follow a similar pattern. Same deal with `Opportunity`.