# Find all Profiles that can Edit or Update an Account

Tags: soql, permissions

Can this be done using 1 SOQL Query?  I came up with the following:

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Profile
WHERE Id in
    (SELECT Parent.ProfileId
    FROM ObjectPermissions
    WHERE SObjectType = 'Account'
      AND (PermissionsCreate = true OR PermissionsEdit = true))
```

But this gives me an error:

> The inner select field 'Parent.ProfileId' cannot have more than one level of relationships

This could probably be done in 2 queries, but it would be ideal for me to retrieve in a single result set otherwise I would have to write a script to combine results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just modify my answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153986/2995) slightly to get edit access:

```
SELECT Profile.Name FROM PermissionSet
WHERE IsOwnedByProfile = true AND Id IN (
    SELECT ParentId FROM ObjectPermissions
    WHERE PermissionsEdit = true
    AND SObjectType = 'Account'
)
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right :) I might just delete this Q and upvote your other answer.  Thanks.

Comment: Or maybe I'll just keep it... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265736/should-i-delete-my-question-if-it-is-marked-as-a-duplicate - In any case, thanks!

Comment: @dana Great find on Meta! Creating canon. :) Tis a good signpost.