# SOQL query for all Users who have read access to Task object

Tags: apex, soql, permissions, sobject, standard-objects

I am trying to write a SOQL query to find a list of Users who have read access to the standard Task object but my query keeps coming back empty. Is there a better way to do this?

I have a dropdown list populated with Users but they need to all have read permissions to the Task object.

Here is what I currently have that is returning 0 results:

```
SELECT AssigneeId 
FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
WHERE PermissionSetId 
IN (
    SELECT ParentId 
    FROM ObjectPermissions
    WHERE PermissionsRead = true
    AND SObjectType = 'Task'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is only querying against `PermissionSetAssignment`. Do you want to see user's that have permission sets with read access to `Task` objects or are you looking for any user who's profile has read access?

If you want to see profiles with read access you can use:

```
SELECT Parent.Profile.Name 
FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = true 
AND SObjectType = 'MyObject__c'
```

From there it would be trivial to query for users with the profiles that are returned.

[This post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/153986/query-which-profiles-have-read-access-to-specific-object) asked a similar question (from which the answer was sourced).

Comment: Thanks, I looked at that post earlier but all the examples provided give me no results when I put "Task" as the object, even your example. Not sure why its empty on Task and not for any other object like Account

Answer (score 1):

After stumbling across this question (as well as the above linked question) in search of an answer, I think I've figured out two partial solutions that make a whole. Like you, I attempted to query `FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE SObjectType = Task/Event/Activity` to no avail.

This query will pull all permission sets that have Activities access, and then grab all `AssigneeIds` for `User` records that have applicable `PermissionSetAssignments`:

```
List<PermissionSetAssignment> permSetsWithAccess = [
    SELECT AssigneeId
    FROM PermissionSetAssignment
    WHERE PermissionSetId
    IN (SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet WHERE (PermissionsEditEvent = true OR PermissionsEditTask = true))
];
```

Optionally, you can add any of the following depending on what you are specifically looking for:

```
(PermissionsActivitiesAccess = true OR PermissionsEditEvent = true OR PermissionsEditTask = true)
```

Documentation for UserPermissionAccess [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_UserPermissionAccess.htm).

The second half of the equation is the following query for checking profile access:

```
List<User> usersWithAccessViaProfile = [
    SELECT Id
    FROM User
    WHERE ProfileId
    IN (SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE (PermissionsEditEvent = true OR PermissionsEditTask = true))
];
```

From here, you can put iterate through the `List<PermissionSetAssignment>` to put everything into a `List<User>`, and then put both `List<User>s` into a single set to get your users where access to specified activities is `true`:

```
List<User> usersWithAccessViaPerms = new List<User>();

for(PermissionSetAssignment psa : permSetsWithAccess) {
    usersWithAccessViaPerms.add(new User(Id=psa.AssigneeId));
}

Set<User> usersWithAccess = new Set<User>(usersWithAccessViaPerms)
usersWithAccess.addAll(usersWithAccessViaProfile);

return usersWithAccess;
```

Voila, you've now got a set of `User` records that have access to the `Task` or `Event` objects.